# Odoo Space Between Buttons on Top Tree View

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I'm able to create a button when select multiple record by adding this header tag in tree view

```
<tree create="false" delete="false">
    <header>
        <button name="action_cancel" type="object" string="Cancel" class="btn-danger"/>
    </header>
    ...
    ...
</tree>
```

[image: button-on-tree-view]

As you can see, there is no space button **8 selected button** and **cancel button**. How can I add a space for that buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `ml4` class to `action_cancel` button

```
<button name="action_cancel" type="object" string="Cancel" class="btn-danger ml4"/>
```

Or alter the `o_list_selection_box` and define the right margin:

```
.o_list_selection_box {
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

*Alter the `web.assets_backend` template to add the CSS file*